# Excel 2013: Using the Search()-function through a table column?

Tags: excel, search

I'm trying to search through a table column and use the `Search()`-function to find out if any of the words in the column appear in a given cell.

[image]

As you can see here, the formula returns FALSE, even though "Chicken" is in the list. If I move "Chicken" to the top in the column, it will return true. This leads me to believe that the formula only looks at the first item in the column.

Upon entering the formula, I used the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> keys to make sure it's an array formula.

Does anyone know why it doesn't look through each of the rows in the column?

Edit: I guess the formula stops when it gets any value (even if that value is false)? Maybe there is a function for searching until true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this non CSE formula:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Table1[Search words],A1)))*1)>0,TRUE,FALSE)
```

The reason is that without Sum() or Sumproduct, it is only returning the first iteration.

[image]